# Where does Visual Studio 2019 CMake project Linux remote builder place sources and output files on target device?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am building a C++ app for Linux and I'm using Visual Studio's CMake integration to remotely build the app. I have made some modifications to the project's directory structure, and now the output executable file has the same name as a folder that previously was part of the project. Now the program compiles well, but the linker fails with the following error: Cannot modify x: is a directory. I figured that if I clean the target folder the build would succeed. However, I cannot find the project folder anywhere on the target machine's file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used that software before, but from [the default config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-configure?view=vs-2019) i'm guessing it is under `~/.vs/yourProjectName`:

```
{
      ...,
      "remoteMachineName": "${defaultRemoteMachineName}",
      "remoteCMakeListsRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/src",
      "remoteBuildRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/build/${name}",
      "remoteInstallRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/install/${name}",

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the whole ~/.vs directory and now it builds fine.